# indexing poisition

Tags: indexing

```
    string letter;
    char words[5] = { 'd','o','g','s','a'};
    for (char i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << words[i] << " ";
        cout;
    }
    cout << "enter letter: ";
    cin >> letter;
    (words.find(letter));

    int position= words.find(letter);
    cout << "position is " << position+ 1 << endl;


bool binarySearch (char usedLetters[], int numGuessedLetters, char guess)
{

    int length = sizeof(usedLetters) / sizeof(usedLetters[0]);
    cout << length << endl;

    int first = 0; 
    int last = length - 1; 
    int mid;  

    while (first <= last)
    {   mid = (first + last) / 2; 
        if (usedLetters[mid]== guess)
            return true;
        if (usedLetters[mid] > guess)
            last = mid - 1;
        else
            first = mid + 1; 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

i am trying to search the array. i want to be able to enter a letter and get given the position of the letter. It is not working at the moment. I get given a error underneath both "words" the error says "char words[14] Error: expersion must have class type. Any suggestions how to make this code work. Addition is there a way to implement this binary search? any help is useful

Comment: char[] doesn't have functions. can you post the code of find?

Comment: You are trying to find a string, not a single letter (even though the string contains only one letter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c++ way would be to use `std::string` instead of `char[]`, like this:

```
  std::string letter;
  std::string words = "dogsa";
  std::cout << "enter letter: ";
  std::cin >> letter;

  int position = words.find(letter);
  std::cout << "position is " << position + 1 << std::endl;
```

If you are stack with `char[]` for some reason, then you can always convert this to `std::string` like this:

```
  std::string letter;
  char words[5] = { 'd','o','g','s','a'};
  std::cout << "enter letter: ";
  std::cin >> letter;
  std::string sentence (words,5);
  int position = sentence.find(letter);
  std::cout << "position is " << position + 1 << std::endl;
```

or manually iterate the array, like this:

```
  std::string letter;
  char words[5] = { 'd','o','g','s','a'};
  std::cout << "enter letter: ";
  std::cin >> letter;
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    if (words[i] == letter[0])
      std::cout << "position is " << i + 1 << std::endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::find`:

```
auto pos = std::find(std::cbegin(words), std::cend(words), 's');
if (pos != std::cend(words)) {
    std::cout << "found : '" << *pos 
              << "' at position: " << std::distance(std::cbegin(words), pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write `words.find(letter);`. Words is an array and an array is not an object.
You should write a function which does the search for the letter and returns it's position.

Answer (score 0):

Use existing libraries, it's *faster*, *safer* and more *readable*.

You can use `std::find`, and to get the position you can subtract the result from `find` with result from `begin()`:

```
int main()
{
   vector<char> vec { 'd', 'o', 'g', 's', 'a' };
   auto to_find = 'g';
   auto result = find(cbegin(vec), cend(vec), to_find);

   if (result != cend(vec)) 
      cout << "Index: " << (result - cbegin(vec)) << '\n';
   else 
      cout << "Not found" << '\n';
}
```

If your compiler doesn't support C++14, you can use `begin()` & `end()` or `vec.begin()` & `vec.end()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can't call find on an array of chars.

```
  (words.find(letter));  // Not correct
```

Based on the way words is declared, that won't work.